# Simple question: Intuition for x and 1-x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In Trigonometry for Dummies (2014 edition), the author writes, "If you look at Figure 10-7, you see that two right triangles are formed. The two triangles
share a side — the one opposite the measured acute angle in each. Call the length of that shared side $y$. The two adjacent sides add up to 1 mile, so you can keep the variables to a minimum by naming one side $x$ and the other $(1 – x)$."

[image]

What is the intuition behind describing that segment as $x$ and $(1-x)$? Is this related to a % of whole or part?

Comment: You should include the figure in your post. Links in questions are generally frowned upon.

Comment: I have extracted the image in question.

Comment: Thank you Simon S and RecklessReckoner. I'll post the image next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two adjacent sides, with lengths, say, $x$ and $y$. But these sides have total length $1$. In other words, $x+y=1$. Subtracting $x$ on both sides shows $y=1-x$, so there's no need to use $y$ separately at all: just replace it with the more specific $1-x$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.